# OpenXML reading from spreadsheet stuck on first row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openxml

I am running some openXML based code in c sharp that's stuck on the first row of data and just loops it again and again. I'm clear that I need to incorporate the row variable into the mix but have tried various methods to no avail. Anyone have any ideas on this?

In the code block below, sst.ChildElements[7].InnerText gets back the content of the first row column 7 but each time the row loops its the content from the same CELL! I want to move onto the next row :-(

```
string fileName = @"c:\temp\accountData.xlsx";

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fs, false))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
        SharedStringTablePart sstpart = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
        SharedStringTable sst = sstpart.SharedStringTable;

        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
        Worksheet sheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;

        var cells = sheet.Descendants<Cell>();
        var rows = sheet.Descendants<Row>();

        Console.WriteLine("Row count = {0}", rows.LongCount());
        Console.WriteLine("Cell count = {0}", cells.LongCount());

        CompanyProvider cp = _db.GetCompanyProvider();
        int i = 0;

        // Or... via each row
        foreach (Row row in rows.ToList())
        {
            if (i == 0)
                i = i + 1;
            else
            {
                CustomerAddress customerAddress = new CustomerAddress();
                customerAddress.AddressLine1 = sst.ChildElements[7].InnerText; // Code hidden for brevity

                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a foreach but you never use row object. Why?

Comment: Any attempt I make to use the row object I cannot get it to work. row.Elements may be the start but cannot get the expression I need. I want to reference each column one by one on the row via 0,1,2,3,4 for column etc so i can populate fields in db. The examples all loop cells

Comment: Are all cells filled in in your spreadsheet? For example if you have the first cell of a row empty, then `ChildElements[7]` will be the 8th cell. Also you can use `foreach(Row row in rows.Skip(1).ToList())` instead of the integer check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the code block below, sst.ChildElements[7].InnerText gets back the content of the first row column 7 but each time the row loops its the content from the same CELL!

This is because you are always reading the value from element `7` in the [`SharedStringsTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278314.aspx) (your `sst` variable) and not the value from element 7 in the `Row` (your `row` variable).

The Shared Strings Table is a mechanism used within OpenXML to prevent duplicate data appearing in cells (to reduce the file size). Instead of a cell containing a string value directly it can instead contain an integer which is the index into the shared strings table. That way if a string is repeated many times within an Excel file it is only stored once but with many references to that string.

You can tell whether or not a `Cell` object contains a shared string index by looking at its [`DataType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.celltype.datatype%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property (note that strings *can* be stored in-line and other datatypes such as numbers are always stored in-line).

If a cell does hold a shared string index then you can use *that* value to index your `sst` property to get the correct content:

```
 sst.ChildElements[<cell content here>].InnerText
```

To get the rows cells by index you can grab the child `Cell`s of the `Row` and then use the [`Enumerable<T>.ElementAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb299233%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to get the `Cell` at the index you require:

```
row.Elements<Cell>().ElementAt(7); //gives the 8th Cell in row - read the "HOWEVER" section!!
```

Using the above, your `foreach` would then become something like:

```
foreach (Row row in rows.ToList())
{
    if (i == 0)
        i = i + 1;
    else
    {
        //get the cell at index 7
        Cell cell = row.Elements<Cell>().ElementAt(7); //read the warning below

        //check the type
        if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType == CellValues.SharedString)
        {
            //it's a shared string so use the cell inner text as the index into the 
            //shared strings table
            Console.WriteLine(sst.ChildElements[int.Parse(cell.InnerText)].InnerText);
        }
        else
        {
            //it's NOT a shared string, output the value directly
            Console.WriteLine(cell.InnerText);
        }

        i = i + 1;
    }

}
```

**HOWEVER...**

The above code will work BUT indexing the cells in the way you are trying to do is error prone. The OpenXML schema allows for empty cells (and rows) to be omitted from the file. This means if you have an empty cell somewhere you may end up picking up the wrong value.

For example, I created a file in Excel with the following structure:
[image: Excel file with empty B2 cell]

Running the above code on that file produces the output:

> 9
>   8

Note that on the first row we parse we end up getting the value from `I2` but on the second row we read we get the value from `H3`. The first row we read is out by one (assuming that by the 7th index you mean you want column `H`) because there is no column `B` in the XML for that row. That is the reason most of the code you'll find that reads Excel files uses a loop to iterate over the cells.

Answer (score 0):

The basic algorithm to interate through rows involves two loops. One for rows the other for cells.

Suppose you have a worksheet.

This is how you get a collection of rows.

```
IEnumerable<Row> rows = worksheet.Descendants<Row>();
```

In a row you hav a collection of cells.

So you need to have a first loop on rows

```
foreach (Row row in rows)
{
}
```

Here you can get a collection of cell for a row

```
IEnumerable<Cell> cells = row.Descendants<Cell>()
```

And then you can iterate through cells in the inner loop

```
foreach (Cell cell in cells)
{
  //Here goes the logic of reading cell value
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm trying to just reference a column for a given row without looping cells. Since on each row I want to reference the fields via their logical index no, col 1, col 2 etc